# What's the largest resolution image file silverlight can support?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, graphics, upload

Just wondering as I'm debugging a problem related to image file sizes.

Is there an upper limit? Or is it just limited by the GPU itself? What about the image file size?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this about file size or image size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used the UPLOAD tag, so I'm assuming you mean uploading an image?

The limit will be set on the server you are uploading to. If it is an ASP.NET app then the httpRuntime element, maxRequestLength attribute in the web.config file controls this limit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=VS.100).aspx